# Bootstrap scrollspy without class nav

Tags: scrollspy

Bootstrap scrollspy need a class `nav` at `<ul>`

How can use a custom class without class `nav`?

Like this

```
<ul class="custom-class">
  <li><a href="#home"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#about"></a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Thanks.